# Enable Auto-Completion for Sublime plugin API

Tags: python, sublimetext2

Is there a way/plugin to enable autocompletion for the Sublime Text 2 plugin api ([Link](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api-reference)) **in** the actual Sublime editor?

I have SublimeCodeintel and Python autocompletion installed - but the sublime python modules are not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin.
https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete
It helps alot. And you should read the following article:
http://dbader.org/blog/setting-up-sublime-text-for-python-development

Comment: I actually have this plugin installed - but even this plugin has to know what the api signature looks like. Have you got it to work with this?